# C# :error There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I used to call several functions with this connection string:

```
class Solders_DB
{
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand query;
        String command;

        public Solders_DB() 
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=Scheduling_Employee ;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

            query = new SqlCommand();
         }
```

As you see I used this `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` in my connection but in this function :

```
    command = @"SELECT [GID]   FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Solder] where [ID]=@ID";

    query.CommandText = command;
    query.Parameters.Clear();
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

    Object o= query.ExecuteScalar();
```

I faced with this error:

> There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first

Comment: I think it is self explanatory :) It means you have connection open that has to be closed first.

Comment: Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections.

Comment: @loop sorry i edite my  title error

Comment: Can you show the code for the SQL that's run before this one?

Comment: Just close the connection and open it again before executing the query that will solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question is not complete. Please explain yourself better for further assistance.

When using a SqlConnection is recommended to use the 'using' statement like this:

```
using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
         try
         {
             SqlConn.Open();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
             return null;
         }

}
```

You're trying to read data from the first execution of your query, please update your question and put the complete code and the error stack.

Answer (score 0):

Its usually when there was another query before that one and has not yet stopped executing inside the database engine (maybe it was a heavy script). You could try `query = new SqlCommand();`, `query.Cancel()` or

`while(query.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open){ Threading.Sleep(100);}`